# Can I prevent zero initialization of the elements in an array data member in a non-POD class?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization

Non-POD derived class PayloadMessage contains an array data member (_payload) whose elements appear to be getting zero initialized upon construction.  I don't want this to happen for performance/efficiency reasons -- it is a large array.  Suggestions?  (Placement new maybe?)  I'm using an older g++ compiler, 3.4.6.

```
#include <iostream>
class BaseMessage {
public:
  enum CCC_MessageType {  START_THREAD, KILL_THREAD };
  CCC_MessageType _type;
  virtual ~BaseMessage() {}  // class has other non-POD class stuff
};
class PayloadMessage : public virtual BaseMessage {
public:
  uint16_t _payload_length;
  uint8_t  _payload[3000];
};
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  PayloadMessage* m = new PayloadMessage;
  size_t i = 0;
  for(; i < 3000; i++) { 
    std::cout << ' ' <<  static_cast<int>(m->_payload[i]); // all zeros, not what I want
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Okay, based on comments/answers, and some testing (shown below), the array is not being initialized.  (Does anyone know what might be causing the memory to appear to be zero-ed out?)

To performance test, I changed main() to the following:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  PayloadMessage* m = new PayloadMessage;
  size_t i = 0;
  for(; i < 1400000; i++) {  // allocates just under 4GB, for 32-bit compatibility
    m = new PayloadMessage;
  }
}
```

Then compiled and ran a timed test:

```
$ g++ -O3 test.cpp
$ time ./a.out
real    0m7.068s
user    0m1.393s
sys     0m4.730s
```

I then added a constructor to do explicit value initialization for _payload and ran the test again:

```
PayloadMessage() : _payload() {}

$ g++ -O3 test.cpp
$ time ./a.out
real    0m10.361s
user    0m3.582s
sys     0m5.797s
```

Yep, the second version with the explicit initialization takes longer, so I assume the first version is not doing initialization (it just looks that way).  Thanks all for your help.

Comment: I have to ask. Is it *really* causing performance loss?  Have you profiled it to be sure?

Comment: Are you sure the buffer really gets zero-initialized? It shouldn't. Did you try to switch on high optimizations (perhaps -O3)?

Comment: If you are getting all zeroes there, it is mere coincidence, unless it is some debug option.

Comment: The buffers are only zero initialized when a `PayloadMessage` is defined in namespace scope or as a local/class static.

Comment: @caveman, thanks for the profiling idea (should have thought of that).

Comment: @Vlad, tried -O3, thanks, but no change (but that's because it wasn't initializing after all)
@PigBen, yep, coincidence, but I'd like to find out what is causing the coincidence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POD is only explicitly value initialized when using `()` (8.5 in the C++ standard), otherwise, it is default initialized. Default initialization of POD means it does not do anything to the memory. If `operator new` is returning zero initialized memory, then the constructor of `PayloadMessage` isn't doing any extra work. Out of curiosity, did you inspect the disassembly of `PayloadMessage`'s constructor to determine if it's actually doing anything expensive?

Comment: no I didn't look at the disassembly.  Good idea, but the performance test (see EDIT in Question) was easier.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason this array should be zero initialized : I think you should check the documentation of your particular implementation (debug options maybe ?).

Answer (score 2):

Can you use `std::vector` and `push_back` (optionally with `reserve`) instead? This allows you to construct the object exactly when you need to.

EDIT: This also removes the need for a length variable.

EDIT2: Assuming your current code works correctly have you actually confirmed via profiling that the initialization is actually a bottleneck in your code? This may be strictly a premature optimization.

Comment: The _payload will be used to store bytes read from a UDP socket, so using push_back() here would not be efficient.  Thanks for the profiling idea.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question in the edit "Does anyone know what might be causing the memory to appear to be zero-ed out?"

You are allocating a large amount of memory, so operator new is requesting a new block of virtual memory from the operating system. As a security feature, all current operating systems ensure that virtually allocated memory is cleared before a process can read from it. This is to ensure process isolation so that you cannot read memory that was previously written to and freed by another process.

Avoiding memory becoming zeroed out at the time of the first access is not possible, but you can use a custom memory allocator to reuse a pool of virtual memory that you request from the operating system. This will allow subsequent requests to avoid the clear. Keeping the virtual memory is opposite of the default behavior of operator delete, which is to return the virtual memory to the operating system for large allocations. It may also be possible to adjust the threshold of the default allocator for when it performs virtual allocations and deallocations, but that is system dependent.